# ¿Cómo cambiar el background de un div dinamicamente con JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

¡Hola! Estoy haciendo una página web de practica (recien inicio en esto del JS) y quiero hacer un slider en un `div`. Me interesa que cambie nada más la imagen.

Sé que iría un `setInterval`pero no sé cual sería la estructura de la `function` para hacer que cada cierto tiempo el fondo cambie.

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, pero atendiendo a tu petición

Si quieres cambiar la imagen de fondo de un div:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $('#id-de-div').css('background-image', 'ruta/imagen.jpg');
}, 5000);//Colocas el tiempo que desees aquí, debe de estar en milisegundos
```

Si quieres cambiarle una imagen dentro del div:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $('#id-de-img').attr('src', 'ruta/imagen.jpg');
}, 5000);
```

Ahora que si quieres mantener las imagenes para que el usuario pueda cambiar entre ellas, es un poco más largo el proceso, para esto, yo te sugeriría el siguiente plugin para crear un slider:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/